# AppDynamics Reuse nodename in Machine Agent Registration

Tags: appdynamics

We have implemented AppDynamics in Jboss application. We have load balancer and autoscalling which means we will have node registration when new server comes up.

The problem here is Java and Machine Agent. Java Agent can reuse name with prefix (Appd Controlled Node Names) , but machine agent node name need to be provided at configuration level.

We are getting two separate agents listed. One is 100% with Machine Agent and another with Java agent. We need Machine Agent will ping at same line.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhpeU.png

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is resolved. 
The controller-info of Machine Agent need not to have any Application,Node and Tier name. It should include unique host id which should be same as controller-info of JavaAgent.